# What is the most efficient method for loading widgets in functions.php

Tags: functions, widgets, include

I have seen WordPress developers use two different methods for loading custom widgets from the functions.php file.

The first:

```
include("functions/my-custom-widget.php");
```

The second:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/functions/my-custom-widget.php");
```

Which one of these methods is more efficient. I'm particularly interested in performance if there is a difference at all. Does the require_once follow better 'best practices' ?

I'm sure there are plenty of other ways of doing this. If anyone has a better recommendation I would love to hear it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are acceptable but not recommended. Use [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) instead because a child theme can overwrite the loaded file then.

Example:

```
$found = locate_template( 'functions/my-custom-widget.php', TRUE, TRUE );
```

The first `TRUE` tells WordPress not only to *search* for the file but to *load* it actually. The second makes it a `require_once` call.

The function return the path to the located file in case you need it later. If nothing is found it returns an empty string.

Comment: Great. Didn't know locate_template() existed. This will come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

`require_once` ([PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php))

> will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

This check will take more time. If you know what you're doing (including), then you should ditch the `_once` part and save time.

EDIT: you won't see the difference with only a few files. But if you don't include lots of files, you won't mess up your include/require either with a thing as simple as a WP theme, so IMHO there's no point in preventing multiple calls to the same file.

About the difference between `require()` and `include()`:

> **require** is identical to **include** except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error.
>   In other words, it will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.